# event.preventdefault not working when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to submit data to a php page without reloading the page. I have some code but it doesnt seem to work right - it sends me to the the page specified in `action`

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h3j2ht9v/

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
                        <div id="form">
                            <form action="form.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
                                <span>Name</span>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="Enter your name" tabindex=1 />
                                <span>Email</span>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Enter your email" tabindex=2 />
                                <span>Message</span>
                                <textarea class="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" tabindex=3></textarea>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send e-mail" class="submit" tabindex=4>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#contactForm").submit(function (e) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  e.preventDefault();
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), msg: $('#message').val() } );

  /* Alerts the results */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    alert('success');
  });
});
</script>
```

Edit: In console I am getting an error on `$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {` saying `uncaught referenceerror`

Comment: #form is just a div.. use $('form') or class or id for form not for div

Comment: It should be `$("#contactForm")` or `$("#form form")` the actual form and not the div around the form.

Comment: Because you cannot `.submit()` a `div`.

Comment: Why are you editing the OP to only break your code further?  Now instead of attaching `.submit()` to a `div`, you're attaching it to an `id` that doesn't even exist.

Comment: I fixed up the code according to the comments and answers but it is still not working.

Comment: It's working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/h3j2ht9v/1/  ~ It was broken because your jsFiddle was not constructed properly... you failed to include jQuery and you are not supposed to use `<script>` tags in the JavaScript pane.

Answer (score 1):

You did not use form id. Use form ID instead.

```
<div id="form">
    <form action="form.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
        <span>Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="Enter your name" tabindex=1 />
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Enter your email" tabindex=2 />
        <span>Message</span>
        <textarea class="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" tabindex=3></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send e-mail" class="submit" tabindex=4>
    </form>
</div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#contactForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this ),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );
    var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), msg: $('#message').val() } );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I oversaw that but it is still not working.

Comment: @ViruZX, probably because your code is a mess.  There is no `id` called `form` in the OP.  And you're not using jsFiddle properly if that's where you're testing this.

Comment: @ViruZX, It's working when you remember to add jQuery to the jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/h3j2ht9v/1/

Comment: @ViruZX I tried you full code. It works. May be you did not add jQuery. Try as I updated.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function (e) {
   // Your code
   return false;
});
```

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) about the difference between `preventDefault()` and `return false` with some great answers.